# How to swap ETH to WETH on Uniswap

Tags: contract-development, tokens, uniswap, defi

I'm trying to swap ETH to WETH tokens within contract, but cannot find any information how to do it. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pair on uniswap WETH / ETH:

> https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?inputCurrency=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2

and the contract address

> https://etherscan.io/token/0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2